# how to print or echo JSON.stringify data i php

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

i am trying to fetch google contact list using contact api. i got the result and its showing in chrome and firefox console. i want to print the data in php. on the same page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       function auth() {
         var config = {
           'client_id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
           'scope': 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds'
         };
         gapi.auth.authorize(config, function() {
           fetch(gapi.auth.getToken());  

         });
       }

       function fetch(token) {
         $.ajax({
         url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json",
         dataType: "jsonp",
         success:function(data) {

             //alert(JSON.stringify(data));
                                  // display all your data in console
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

         }
         });
     } 
    </script>
```

i tried ajax but not worked. is there any best way to do it. `JSON.stringify(data)` is a array

Comment: You can't have your AJAX call ask for data from a page you don't own. You need to make the AJAX call to your server, have your PHP then go make the request to Google, and then send the data from Google back to your JavaScript.

Comment: Is this page emebded in php?

Comment: i just want to print JSON.stringify(data) in php

Comment: If u have ajax call it means ur php script finished his job.Now total controll to JS.So,How you want to print it

Comment: In PHP you have json_decode() and json_encode() which translates between the stringified JSON version and a array/object-structure of PHP. But I'm not able to understand what you are trying, what is your goal and what is your current approach?

Answer (score 0):

You have nothing to do with `PHP` here. You are receiving a `callback` from `$.ajax` and the only way to show that data on ur page is to use `JavaScript/jQuery`.

See example below on how to parse `$.ajax` callback and `.append()` the data to some element on ur page:

```
<div id="contacts"></div>


function fetch(token) {
   $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?access_token=" + token.access_token + "&alt=json",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success:function(data) {
         $.each(data.feed.entry,function(){                    
            $('#contacts').append('<div>Name: ' + this.title.$t + ' Phone: ' + this.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t + '</div>');
            console.log('Name: ' + this.title.$t + ' Phone: ' + this.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t);
         });

       }
   });
}
```

**Note: if You need to parse ur data with `PHP` then You have to use `curl`.**

Comment: @AseshaGeorge, have You included `jQuery` & `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js`?

Comment: i am getting values in console

Comment: And where is ur problem then? I've included in my example how You can do that!